# correct way of implementing this older R70 threejs code to work with newer version

Tags: javascript, three.js, camera, quaternions

I have this bit of code which is throwing an error. However, it works in this jsfiddle just fine. I'm trying to rotate a cube and also pan it with trackball controls. This works in the fiddle but when I bring it into visual studio it's throwing this error in chrome, "Cannot read property 
'multiplyQuaternions' of undefined".

https://jsfiddle.net/perrinprograms/n6u6asza/668/

This is the code which I am trying to implement. I'm guessing it's because the fiddle is using an older version of three.js and I am using a newer one in my project. Does anyone know if there is a way to properly write this line,  "geometry.quaternion"? Thanks.

```
var geometry = new THREE.Geometry(); 

deltaRotationQuaternion = new THREE.Quaternion()
                    .setFromEuler(new THREE.Euler(
                        toRadians(deltaMove.y * 0.4),
                        toRadians(deltaMove.x * 0.4),
                        0,
                        'XYZ'
                    ));
            geometry.quaternion.multiplyQuaternions(deltaRotationQuaternion, geometry.quaternion);
         }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`THREE.Geometry` doesn't have a `quaternion` property (and from what I can tell, r70 didn't have it either).

`THREE.Object3D` *does* have that property, and is the base class for `THREE.Mesh`, so you can use it like this:

```
var myMesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
myMesh.quaternion.multiplyQuaternions(deltaRotationQuaternion, myMesh.quaternion);
```

**Edit:** Looking at your fiddle, it looks like you already figured that out, correct?

three.js r87

Comment: OH! Yea. I overlooked that due to some confusing naming conventions in my project and also because I hadn't eaten lunch yet. Thank Jim!